# solaris equivalent of /proc/self/environ LFI

Tags: attacks, exploit, solaris, file-inclusion

I need to exploit a Solaris vulnerability for class, but we never dealt with Solaris before and I never installed it.

Does Solaris have an equivalent to Linux's `/proc/self/environ`, exposing a process's environment as a file, that allows local file inclusion attacks?

Answer (score 3):

On Solaris, you get a process environment with these commands:

```
pargs $$
pargs -e $$
```

There is no shortcut like /proc/self with Solaris so you need to know the PID of the process, eg.:

```
/proc/$$/psinfo
```

Moreover, only the arguments are visible here, the environment is in /proc/*pid*/as and I doubt this file to be exploitable with LFI as it is kind of a sparse file with which you need to seek to precise locations for the read to succeed.